# What does "jointy cigarette" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, british-english, spoken-english

I heard the term "jointy cigarette" in an video about Sir Arthur Schuster: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efOzHkl6GJ8&feature=youtu.be&t=34s

But what does this mean? The web search only shows the connection to cannabis. 
Is this term describing that it is a hand rolled cigarette? 
Or does it relate to the inclusion of a filter or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word on the video is "jaunty".

The relevant definition from the Oxford English Dictionary is:

> Easy and sprightly in manner; having or affecting well-bred or easy
>   sprightliness; affecting airy self-satisfaction or unconcern.

The use of "jaunty" is an example of the common figure of speech called [hypallage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypallage): "jaunty" really describes the person, but is applied to the cigarette, as that is what exemplifies his jauntiness.

Comment: If you activate the subtitles, they show "jointy", too. And i really cannot hear a "jaunty", even regarding the British accent. Regardless of this, the definition you posted seems quite poetic, which does not match with the kind of expression the speaker is usually using. So thank you very much, but currently I am not satisfied with this answer. Perhaps you could give some further detail to consolidate it?

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach -- "Jaunty" describes the attitude or manner of the relevant person.  In this context, the cigarette is held or used in a way that is consistent with other people getting this impression about the cigarette's smoker.

Comment: Can't place the regional accent here, @ColinFine. Studs become _stoods_ and _jaunty_ becomes _j/oh/nty_. Do you recognize it?

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach You are well advised to believe it when folks who have been listening to English all their lives tell you what is spoken by an English speaker. In this case, the word is certainly _jaunty_ just as Mr Fine says. I think the OED entry is as authoritative a detail as you are liable to find. If this disappoints you, of course, you may continue to imagine that he says "jointy," and no-one will be any worse off.

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach: it is certainly "jaunty", whatever the subtitles may say. It sounds to me like an antipodean accent - Australian or NZ. The use of "jaunty" is an example of the common figure of speech called [hypallage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypallage): "jaunty" really describes the person, but is applied to the cigarette, as that is what exemplifies his jauntiness.

Comment: @ColinFine The man saying jaunty has an English accent (not sure of the region), but the presenter has and AUS/NZ accent.

Comment: @P.E.Dant: If you believe every thing anybody in the internet has to say without questioning it you really should not behave as arrogant as the comment you wrote shows. If you don't like a discussion about it, then you could simply leave it.

Comment: I think some of the information from the comments should be incorporated into the answer. If someone is searching for "hypallage" it would be nice if this example came up in their results.

Comment: The man who says "jaunty" is Keith Moore, Head Librarian at the Royal Society. His accent is Northern (but not a broad Northern) I would guess at Cumbrian, but I'm no Henry Higgins.

Comment: @JamesK I've never heard the Cumbrian turn _studs_ into _stewds_. But I am far from an authority on British regional accents. Drop me in Wessex and I might as well be in the Gambia for all that I'll understand half a word.

Comment: I have confirmed with Mr. Moore at the Royal Society and he says: "**I said 'jaunty' in the sense of amused stylishness.**"